# Sharing List<T> with BackgroundWorker across two forms

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm trying to build a little image widget. It's supposed to starts up with a splash screen that loads images from an XML list, puts them in a List inside an object, and then closes that form and returns to the MainWindow. I use a BackgroundWorker on the splash screen so I can exit out if I want.

As far as I can tell the splash screen is working, at least the list's Count shows it has objects in it when the MainWindow checks. The problem I'm having is when I try to access the objects in the List. Then I get the following error: *The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.*

I've tried Delegates, a static object, and even passing a copy of the MainWindow into the Splash form (which is the version I'm pasting). However, I cannot solve this problem. Any help would be welcome.

**Splash.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Yvonne1
{
    public partial class Splash : Window
    {
        public BackgroundWorker bw;
        public string url = @"http://domain.com/pics-list.php";
        public MainWindow mw;
        public XmlNodeList xl;
        public Splash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetupWorker();
            FetchXml();
            progOne.Maximum = xl.Count;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void SetupWorker()
        {
            bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

        private void FetchXml()
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(this.url);
                this.xl = doc.SelectNodes("//image");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                this.DialogResult = false;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bw.CancelAsync();
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }

        public void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int xcount = 0;
            foreach(XmlNode xn in xl)
            {
                string full = xn.FirstChild.InnerText;
                string thumb = xn.LastChild.InnerText;
                BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(thumb));
                mw.p1.New = new Piccy(full, thumb, temp);

                xcount += 1;
                bw.ReportProgress(xcount);

                Thread.Sleep(200);
                if (bw.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true; return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progOne.Value = Double.Parse(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
            int done = int.Parse(progOne.Value.ToString()) - 1;
            Piccy temp = mw.p1.Get(done);
            txtStatus.Text = "Fetched: " + temp.Thumb;
        }

        public void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (progOne.Value == progOne.Maximum)
            {
                this.DialogResult = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (The part with the error.)

```
private void StartUp()
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(p1.Count.ToString());
        Piccy temp = p1.Get(1);
        imgMain.Source = temp.Img;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+"\n\n"+ex.Source+"\n\n"+ex.StackTrace, "Error");
    }
}
```

The line **imgMain.Source = temp.Img;** is where the thread error shows up.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: The **BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(thumb));** line is where the trouble was. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://www.google.com.au/#q=The+calling+thread+cannot+access+this+object+because+a+different+thread+owns+it.&safe=off

Comment: TLDR; ta.speot.is link, you can't change a collection that is bound on the UI thread while in a background thread unless you use FromCurrentSynchronizationContext

Comment: And BitmapImage is bound to the UI thread. I just realized that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this I  hope this will solve your issue

```
private void StartUp()
{
 try
 {
    MessageBox.Show(p1.Count.ToString());
    Piccy temp = p1.Get(1);
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(()=>imgMain.Source = temp.Img);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+"\n\n"+ex.Source+"\n\n"+ex.StackTrace, "Error");
  }
```

}

Comment: A year late, but I just saw this answer. Thank you. An anonymous delegate (lambda?) was what I went with.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Singleton class, which will house a public List. The advantage of using singletons is that there is always one instance of the class/object (and the List too) and that every class or thread can get the Instance of that Singleton class. If implemented correctly that means that you can access all the variables and methods in this Singleton from each class and thread in your program.
Read more and see how to implement it at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650849.aspx